# Zoom out a picture on a social media website

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, professional, publishing

I am trying to upload a profile picture to linkedin.
For some reason it almost always shows the head.
I cannot zoom out further. (Although I can zoom in more)
I want to able to zoom out more and be able to see the shoulders, background etc.

How can I do that? What changes should I make to my image?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to LinkedIn support, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: Reduce the resolution

Comment: @dlkf09 - I would suggest editing the question so it refers to "a picture" on "a website".

Comment: @ Philip Kendall - agreed, but with a small tweak there could be a useful question there. I'd suggest giving dlkf09 a day or so.

Comment: @dlkf09 - You might also want to add some tags to show you've considered the relevance to the site. "Publishing" and "Image Processing" would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands (08:00 BST) the question is a bit too specific, but there is a photographic publication question hidden in there, so I'll answer that.

Many publishers (including websites) have a preferred image size and proportions, measured in physical dimensions (mm, inches) or pixels. If the image you submit is larger than that or differently shaped, they will only display part of the image.

Resize the image using your favourite image processing software so the entire image matches the size they specify.

Comment: +1 but is it worth mentioning proportions as well. The issue sounds more like they're trying to upload a portrait shaped photo where the requirement is for a photo of square proportions

Comment: I had been thinking "size" covered it, but you make a good point. Edited.

Comment: Trim *or pad*, depending.  In some cases, it may be necessary to letterbox the image to get the desired result.  YMMV.